# How do I print a list of strings into a table in python?

Tags: python, string, list, printing

This is the list

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

This is how I want it to look like

> apples Alice  dogs
>
> oranges   Bob  cats
>
> cherries Carol moose
>
> banana David goose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose and use str.join:

```
print("\n".join(" ".join(t) for t in zip(*tableData)))
```

Output:

```
apples Alice dogs
oranges Bob cats
cherries Carol moose
banana David goose
```

`zip(*tableData)` transposes the data:

```
[('apples', 'Alice', 'dogs'), ('oranges', 'Bob', 'cats'), ('cherries', 'Carol', 'moose'), ('banana', 'David', 'goose')]
```

Then we just join the elements from each tuple separated by a space and join the result using a newline as the separator.

Using python3 use can use  `sep`:

```
print(*(" ".join(t) for t in zip(*tableData)), sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

While not providing the exact same output, you might be interested to see how `csvkit` handles drawing tables:

https://github.com/onyxfish/csvkit/blob/master/csvkit/utilities/csvlook.py#L40

You can modify as required (for example removing all the borders if not needed). Went ahead and did that quickly for you:

```
import sys

def draw_table(rows):  
    widths = []

    # Calculate the width of each column
    for row in rows:
        for i, v in enumerate(row):
            try:
                if len(v) > widths[i]:
                    widths[i] = len(v)
            except IndexError:
                widths.append(len(v))

    for i, row in enumerate(rows):

        for j, d in enumerate(row):
            if d is None:
                d = ''
            sys.stdout.write(d.ljust(widths[j] + 1))
        sys.stdout..write('\n')
```

You can then just pass your table data:

```
> draw_table(table_data)

apples oranges cherries banana 
Alice  Bob     Carol    David  
dogs   cats    moose    goose
```